Creating Many Radio Options with Different Image Sources and Values - Visual Studio
So I'm working on a project where one radio name has 96 options and looking for a way to streamline adding all of them rather than manually changing the input's id/value and img's src/alt. I know that I can do something like this:
(label.radio-select>input:radio[id="" value=""]+img[src="" alt="")

to add one and I could apply *96 to create 96 instances of that, but I can't find the syntax to add a different ID/value/src/alt to each one.
Is this possible using Visual Studio? Open to other avenues of achieving this, but I am a beginner so might need a little hand-holding to get there.
EDIT:
It seems like this can be done with regex, but having issues inputting multiple substitution options. I have
/(id-placeholder-\d\d)

and I want to replace the first two instances with "ABC" and the third/fourth with "DEF" and so on. What would be the correct syntax?

you can try the extension I made Regex Text Generator, use Multi-Cursor

You got me going down a rabbit hole. Right now I have "id-placeholder-##" and I want to change the first two instances to "ABC" and the next two instances "DEF", so I have /(id-placeholder-\d\d) as the regular expression. How do I format the substitution correctly in this case. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know! Thank you for any help!

id-placeholder-\d\d(.*?)id-placeholder-\d\d(.*?)id-placeholder-\d\d(.*?)id-placeholder-\d\d - > ABC$1ABC$2DEF$3DEF

you don't show the final text you want to get (show the first 10 and the last 10), if you have 96 options and you use 3 letters of the alphabet per 2 options you don't have enough letters, I don't get this id-placeholder

why tag with VSC if you tool of choice is VS? Does VS support Emmet? The Regex Text Generator extension is for VSC.
